# A criterion for compact topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

A book I'm reading uses the following argument, but I could't see how it works:

*Suppose $X$ is a topological space, $\mathcal{A}$ is a pre-basis for the topology (i.e. the topology on $X$ is the coarsest topology containing $\mathcal{A}$). Suppose that any covering of $X$ by elements in $\mathcal{A}$ has a finite subcovering. Then, by Tychonov theorem, $X$ is compact.*

The Tychonov theorem, as I understand, states that the product of a family of compact spaces is compact. Still I couldn't see how this argument works. In the book the space X and the pre-basis $\mathcal{A}$ is given explicitly, but judging from the context, it seems that the argument above does not depend on the specific form of $X$ or $\mathcal{A}$.

Could you please help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's Alexander's subbasis theorem.

Comment: Daniel Fischer is right that this is the Alexander subbasis theorem. It's often used as a step, indeed the main step, toward the proof of the Tychonoff product theorem, but I've never seen a proof in the other direction, assume Tychonoff and prove Alexander.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks! Perhaps the author made a mistake in quoting the theorem. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks! I read the proof of Tychonoff theorem several years ago but I can't remember any part of it now. Thank you for pointing out the right direction for me!

Comment: A proof of Alexander's subbase lemma and how it proves Tychonov, is at http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2005;task=show_msg;msg=1747 e.g.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Thank you so much!